# Translate Negative Binomial parameters from R to Excel

Tags: r, excel

I applied the `fitdistrplus` package in order to fit an empirical distribution.
It turned out the best fit was the negative binomial distribution with parameters:

```
size=0.6900788
mu=2.6522087

dnbinom(0:10, mu = 2.6522087, size =0.6900788)
[1] 0.33666338 0.18435650 0.12362301 0.08796440 0.06439416 0.04793144 0.03607044 0.02735574 0.02086667 0.01598815 0.01229390
```

I am now trying to generate the same numbers on EXCEL where the parameters are required in different format:

```
NEGBINOMDIST(number_f,number_s,probability_s)
```

How am I meant to do this? Any ideas?
Many thanks..

Comment: `NEGBINOMDIST` doesn't allow `size`, which it calls `number_s` to be less than 1 (it gives a `#NUM` error), and it silently truncates non-integer values. To convert between `mu` and probability see the note in `?dnbinom`

Comment: `dnbinom` is the density function, `NEGBINOMDIST` returns probabilities and is therefore the distribution function, right?

Comment: @Roland, aren't these the same for a discrete distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to  [Microsoft's documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828361), Excel uses the standard "number of draws before n failures" definition; the parameterization used by `fitdistrplus` is the alternative referred to in `?dnbinom` as:

> An alternative parametrization (often used in ecology) is by the
>        *mean* ‘mu’, and ‘size’, the *dispersion parameter*, where ‘prob’
>        = ‘size/(size+mu)’.  The variance is ‘mu + mu^2/size’ in this
>        parametrization.

So if you want to get back from `mu` and `size` to `prob` and `size` (Excel's `probability_s` and `number_s` respectively) you need

```
number_s=size
probability_s=size/(size+mu)

muval <- 2.6522087
sizeval <- 0.6900788
(probval <- sizeval/(sizeval+muval))
## [1] 0.206469
all.equal(dnbinom(0:10,mu=muval,size=sizeval),
          dnbinom(0:10,prob=probval,size=sizeval))
## TRUE
```

However, you're not done yet, because (as commented above by @James) Excel only allows positive integers for `number_s`, and the estimated value above is 0.69.  You may need to search/ask on an Excel-related forum about how to overcome this limitation ... at worst, since Excel does have [an implementation of the gamma function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/gamma-function-HA102753277.aspx), you can use the formula given in `?dnbinom`

```
Gamma(x+n)/(Gamma(n) x!) p^n (1-p)^x
```

to implement your own calculation of the NB (this formulation allows non-integer values of `n`). It would be best to use the `GAMMLN` function in Excel to calculate the numerator and denominator of the normalization constant on the log scale ... if you're lucky, someone out there will have saved you some trouble and implemented this already ...

Comment: I applied the formula: Gamma(x+n)/(Gamma(n) x!) p^n (1-p)^x 
and it worked perfectly fine.
the only issue was that because the GAMMA(x) function is not available in versions prior to Excel 2013, I had to use EXP(GAMMALN(X)).

many thanks guys!

Comment: for what it's worth it would be better (more numerically stable) to compute the log-probability first: `GAMMLN(x+n)-GAMMLN(n)-GAMMLN(x+1) + n*LOG(p) +x*LOG(1-p)` and then exponentiate it ..